# RaspberryPi GPIO assembly program digitalRead returning HIGH without any physical button press

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, gpio, wiringpi

*This Question is a Repost, I figured I would just start all over again seeing as how there were several issues regarding context and formatting in it*

### Program Function:

The function of my program is to blink LEDs on and off through the use of a loop when one of three buttons is pressed.
When `BTN_LEFT` is input and read as `HIGH`, the program should ideally branch to the `BLNKR_LEFT` loop where it should blink `LED_LEFT` on and off until `BTN_LEFT` is read as `LOW`.
When `BTN_HZRD` is read as `HIGH`, the program should branch to the `BLNKR_HZRD` loop and blink `LED_LEFT` and `LED_RIGHT` on and off until `BTN_HZRD` is read as `LOW`
When `BTN_RIGHT` is input and read as `HIGH`, the program should branch to the `BLNKR_RIGHT` loop and blink `LED_RIGHT` on and off until `BTN_RIGHT` is read as `LOW`.
During these three `BLNKR` loops, when their respective `BTN` inputs are returning `LOW`, the program should branch back to the `INPUT` loop and continue reading for input from any of the three buttons.

```asm
// to compile: g++ redLed.s -lwiringPi -g -o redLed
// Program will power an LED when button is pressed, and when button is not pressed, LED will remain off

.equ INPUT, 0
.equ OUTPUT, 1
.equ LOW, 0
.equ HIGH, 1

.equ LED_LEFT, 29   // wiringPi 29 (bcm 21)
.equ LED_RIGHT, 28  // wiringPi 28 (bcm 20)
.equ BTN_LEFT, 23   // wiringPi 23 (bcm 13)
.equ BTN_HZRD, 22   // wiringPi 22 (bcm 6)
.equ BTN_RIGHT, 21  // wiringPi 21 (bcm 5)

.text
.global main
main:
// int main()
    push {lr} // {
    bl wiringPiSetup // wiringPiSetup(); // initialize the wiringPi library
    
    // Initialize our WPI inputs and outputs
    mov r0, #LED_LEFT // pinMode(29,OUTPUT); // set the wpi 29 pin for output
    mov r1, #OUTPUT
    bl pinMode
    
    mov r0, #LED_RIGHT // pinMode(28,OUTPUT); // set the wpi 28 pin for output
    mov r1, #OUTPUT
    bl pinMode
    
    mov r0, #BTN_LEFT  // pinMode(23,INPUT); // set the wpi 23 pin for input
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl pinMode
    
    mov r0, #BTN_HZRD // pinMode(22,INPUT); // set the wpi 22 pin for input
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl pinMode
    
    mov r0, #BTN_RIGHT // pinMode(21,INPUT); // set the wpi 21 pin for input
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl pinMode
    
    // Searches for an input from any button, if there is no input, then the program will keep looping
INPUT:
    // Set both LEDs to LOW
    mov r0, #LED_LEFT
    mov r1, #LOW
    bl digitalWrite
    
    mov r0, #LED_RIGHT
    mov r1, #LOW
    bl digitalWrite
    
    // Read for input from BTN_LEFT, BTN_RIGHT, or BTN_HZRD
    mov r0, #BTN_LEFT
    bl digitalRead    // digitalRead(BTN_LEFT);
    
    mov r1, #HIGH
    cmp r0, r1
    bleq BLNKR_LEFT
    
    // Read for input from BTN_HZRD
    mov r0, #BTN_HZRD
    bl digitalRead
    
    mov r1, #HIGH
    cmp r0, r1
    bleq BLNKR_HZRD
    
    // Read for input from BTN_RIGHT
    mov r0, #BTN_RIGHT
    bl digitalRead
    
    mov r1, #HIGH
    cmp r0, r1
    bleq BLNKR_RIGHT
    b INPUT

BLNKR_LEFT:
    // If BTN_LEFT is not being pressed then the program will return to INPUT
    mov r0, #BTN_LEFT
    bl digitalRead
    
    mov r1, #LOW
    cmp r0, r1
    bleq INPUT
    
    mov r0, #LED_LEFT // digitalWrite(29,HIGH); // write high volt signal to pin 29
    mov r1, #HIGH
    bl digitalWrite

    ldr r0, =#350 // delay(350); // Delay for 350 milliseconds
    bl delay

    mov r0, #LED_LEFT // digitalWrite(29,LOW); // write low voltage to wpi 29 to turn off the led
    mov r1, #LOW
    bl digitalWrite
    
    ldr r0, =#350
    bl delay
    
    b BLNKR_LEFT
    
BLNKR_HZRD:
    // If BTN_HZRD isnt being pressed then the program will branch back to INPUT
    mov r0, #BTN_HZRD
    bl digitalRead
    
    mov r1, #LOW
    cmp r0, r1
    bleq INPUT
    
    // Turn on both LED_LEFT and LED_RIGHT
    mov r0, #LED_LEFT
    mov r1, #HIGH
    bl digitalWrite
    
    mov r0, #LED_RIGHT
    mov r1, #HIGH
    bl digitalWrite
    
    // delay for 350 milliseconds
    ldr r0, =#350 
    bl delay

    // Turn off both LED_LEFT and LED_RIGHT
    mov r0, #LED_LEFT
    mov r1, #LOW
    bl digitalWrite
    
    mov r0,#LED_RIGHT
    mov r1, #LOW
    bl digitalWrite
    
    // Delay for 350 milliseconds
    ldr r0, =#350
    bl delay
    
    b BLNKR_HZRD
    
BLNKR_RIGHT:
    // If BTN_RIGHT isnt being pressed then the program will branch back to INPUT
    mov r0, #BTN_RIGHT
    bl digitalRead
    
    cmp r0, #LOW
    bleq INPUT
    
    // Turn on LED_RIGHT
    mov r0, #LED_RIGHT
    mov r1, #HIGH
    bl digitalWrite
    
    // delay for 350 milliseconds
    ldr r0, =#350 
    bl delay

    // Turn off LED_RIGHT
    mov r0,#LED_RIGHT
    mov r1, #LOW
    bl digitalWrite
    
    // Delay for 350 milliseconds
    ldr r0, =#350
    bl delay
    
    b BLNKR_RIGHT

    mov r0, #0 // return 0;
    pop {pc} // }
```

### The Problem:

When I run the program, either the `BLKNR_LEFT` or `BLNKR_HZRD` loop will begin to run **without** any physical press of either of the three `BTN`s, depending on which `cmp` is executed first.
When I run the program, upon execution of `digitalRead` for `BTN_LEFT` or `BTN_HZRD`, the value stored in `r0` will be `HIGH` even though I did not physically press the button, however, upon execution of `digitalRead` for `BTN_RIGHT`, `r0` will correctly display either `HIGH` or `LOW` depending on whether the button is physically being pressed or not.
I have tried using different button switches, but that didn't seem to fix the issue with `BTN_LEFT` and `BTN_HZRD` returning `HIGH`. [Image of my wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3HKF.jpg) I believe my issue might be lying in my breadboard wiring,and any help regarding this issue would be very appreciated.

### Solution:

So, it turns out the pins that I had my `BTN` values connected to `BCM 5` `BCM 6` were by default supposed to register as `HIGH`, the only one that wasn't defaulted at `HIGH` was `BCM 13` which worked fine. I did not feel interested enough in fixing this or changing the reading of the pins so I simply re-pinned `BTN_LEFT` and `BTN_HZRD` to `BCM 13` and `BCM 19`. Of course, I re-pinned `BTN_RIGHT` to `BCM 26`. These three BCM pins are by default on my `gpio readall` returning as `LOW` and my program works fine now. Thank you guys for all the help because even though the problem was so simple I wouldn't have learnt how to use such a debugger without coming here.

Linked below is a screenshot of `gpio readall` in which the voltage on `BCM` pins `5` and `6` are displaying `1`, while `BCM` pins `13`, `19`, and `26` are reading a voltage of `0`. I have tried using `PUD_DOWN` internal resistors to combat any sort of floating pins there may be.
[screenshot of gpio readall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FztWn.png)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `cmp` e.g. use the gdb command `b 70` (or whatever line that is). Let the program `run`. When stopped `p $r0` to see what `digitalRead` returned. Also you did not show how the buttons are wired. Maybe they are wired in reverse or left as floating which then may produce random values unless you have a pull-up resistor.

Comment: @Jester After running the program in the debugger and checking the value of r0, it seems like  `BTN_LEFT` and `BTN_HZRD` read `HIGH` even when they are not being pressed. The only button which works as intended is `BTN_RIGHT` where, if examined, it will return a value of 0 when not pressed. I have uploaded a picture of my wiring and would love some feedback if this is simply a wiring issue, otherwise I guess it could also be faulty buttons?? Im just guessing here.

Comment: Judging from the breadboard the button is wired to connect to positive rail only and no pull down is present. That means if the button is not pressed it is probably floating and so reads some random value. You need a pull-down resistor. Apparently the Rpi can be configured for internal pull down so use the [pullUpDnControl function](http://wiringpi.com/reference/core-functions/) with `PUD_DOWN`.

Comment: Glad you got your device working, but I would really suggest that you pay attention to the issue of pull-up or pull-down resistors.  You talk about a "default" but there isn't really any such thing; the pin always reads as high or low according to the voltage on it.  Having a pull-down resistor of some relatively high value connected between the pin and ground is how you ensure that, that when nothing else is connected, that voltage will be zero (low).  [...]

Comment: If you don't have either this or a pull-up resistor, then the voltage on an unconnected "floating" pin may be either high or low, more or less randomly.  So, have you actually verified that a pull-down resistor is in place?  Just testing a particular pin to see if it seems to "default" to low isn't a reliable way to check, since if it is actually floating, it may very well *happen* to read as low in all your tests, and then change spontaneously due to some totally unrelated change in hardware or software, or due to a random glitch.  [...]

Comment: And you would be really bummed out if that happens when the device is released and in service.  "My hazard lights randomly switched on in the middle of the night, and ran down my battery" does not make for happy customers.

Comment: @NateEldredge When I used `gpio readall` in my terminal, it was showing that there were a specified number of input pins which their voltage read 1. Among those pins were `BCM` `5` and `6`, this was simply through the use of `gpio readall`  I may have worded it wrong by calling it a default, but the voltage for `bcm` `5` and `6` constantly displayed as having voltage run through them

Comment: @BeefCake: Okay, but what I'm saying is that this is fundamentally something you cannot determine by testing.  If there is not a pull-up or pull-down then you will get a reading that merely reflects whatever charge happens to be on some tiny capacitor somewhere in the chip, which may change (or not change) unpredictably.  So your tests can't prove that pins 5/6 will *always* read as 1 when open, no more than that pins 13/19/26 will always read low.

Comment: @BeefCake: It's the hardware equivalent of reading an uninitialized variable.  If you had `void foo(void) { int a; int b; printf("%d %d", a, b); }` in a C program, and you observed that in all your tests, it printed `0 1`, would you conclude that `a` will always default to 0, and that `b` will always default to 1?  No, that would be absurd.  And that's likewise why you can't deduce the status of a possibly floating pin by doing tests.